# Do HAARP-like programs have effects on climate?

Tags: atmosphere, climate-change, ionosphere

Military powers like USA, Rusia and China have programs to heat through electromagnetic waves the Ionosphere. HAARP supposedly is a research program, but run by part of the military of US (Air Force and Navy) . Rusia has SURA and China IIRC has CSES. Supposedly one of the tests made by these programs affected the city of Vasilsursk where they had electrical alterations. A physicist from China called Gong Shuhong said he followed the tests done by Russia and China in cooperation and that he believes it wont have important consequences in a global scale but that it could have consequences in a regional scale. My question is, is it known if HAARP-like programs have effects on climate? The programs manager said they dont but several articles online mention researchs which says they could.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Frequency_Active_Auroral_Research_Program

Comment: This question should be edited to provide more specific claims and references - as the HAARP program is a focal point of many conspiracy theories, it's very easy to find all sorts of vague or misleading/unsupported discussion online about its impact on climate.

Comment: This question makes people uncomfortable and thus is not PC.  The questioner or the OP needs to cite proof of their question?  Come on. Let's get a conversation going about HAARP.  After all, we PAID for this 'research center'!!

Comment: Conspiracy theories.  Name ONE conspiracy theory that has been proved to be a small group trying to screw up a large group with lies!  Name JUST ONE.  This label gets plastered on anything the Elite don't want to have looked at too closely.  Don't you get it?

Comment: The Lensing that HAARP is into, the magnification of frequencies to see what happens is what HAARP is doing.  Lensing.  You bet that might have an effect and they are experimenting on our planet with our lives our environment.  And what?  You TRUST them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in any significant way.
As an analogy, if you are looking for a suspect responsible for knocking down the trees in a forest, you shouldn't worry about someone carrying a Swiss army knife, it just isn't the right tool.

[HAARP has a power of 3.6 MW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Frequency_Active_Auroral_Research_Program), which is a lot, but nothing compared with the energy in a modest storm. As an example, a single lightning bolt can deliver 1.4 MWh ([5 billion joules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvesting_lightning_energy)) in a fraction of a second, and HAARP would need half an hour to deliver the same amount of energy (assuming perfect efficiency). And a single thunderstorm can deliver hundreds of lightning bots.

HAARP is designed to excite the [ionosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionosphere), a very low density part of the atmosphere where charged particles interact heavily with electromagnetic radiation. But the ionosphere is WAY up, about 60 km high or more (that's 6 times the altitude of commercial flights), and what happens there have little to do with the weather we experience down at the surface. That's why you will never hear about the ionosphere in a TV whether forecast.

For example, [jet streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_stream) that are notable for existing at very high altitude and make an important impact on weather, are 16 km high AT MOST, just around the corner compared with the ionosphere.

To give you a bit more of context, the [record braking sky dive by Felix Baumgartner](https://www.space.com/17961-supersonic-skydive-worlds-highest-space-jump.html), was made from 39 km high, and if you see [the footage of the jump](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvbN-cWe0A0) you will realize that he was almost in outer space. Well, the ionosphere starts 21 km higher than that!

So even if HAARP does create a sizable perturbation of the ionosphere, that wouldn't impact the weather, let alone the climate. It will impact radio communications, but not much more than that.

Comment: [Anthropogenic Space Weather](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11214-017-0357-5) linked in [Is the recently discovered VLF-induced radiation barrier in any way important or useful?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21584/12102) suggests that handwaving away RF sources on Earth having any possible effects might be premature. But indeed HAARP-like experiments probably don't affect Earth's climate.